# How can I vertically center a series of svg circles?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a series of SVG created circles with text next to them each with specific margains in order to create a "C" like shape. I am having difficulty vertically centering them.

My Initial attempt was to create a container with a `<ul>` followed by the series of `<li>`. My idea was that the `<ul>` would contain it's own shape and therefore the container having a full height would center the list, creating what I wanted, unfortunately that did not work as expected.

My second idea was to use to bootstrap4 row and column grid system, but when I set the height to full, the columns completely full and it did not work.a

Here is the code for my list attempt,

```
<div class="nav_bar_container align-middle">
<ul id="nav_bar">
    <li style="margin-left: 50px;" class="nav_child">
        <svg height="100" width="100">
            <circle id="About" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke-width="3" class="expand active"> </circle>
            <text>
                <b> About </b>
            </text>
        </svg>
    </li>
    <li style="margin-left: 15px;" class="nav_child">
        <svg height="100" width="100">
            <circle id="Experience" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke-width="3" class="expand disabled"> </circle>
        </svg>
        <span>
            <b> Experience </b>
        </span>
    </li>

</ul>
<div>
```

Could anyone teach me the proper way to vertically center the elements to create the desired effect?

I need five of my svg circles to create a C like shape, vertically centered on the left of my webpage. However this question primarily requests the vertical centering. I have an image at the top of my screen which makes it frustrating to work with and I therefore always need this css to help,

```
.nav_bar_container {
    background: transparent;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh

}
```

Comment: made #nav_bar in position relative and his <li> children in position absolute, then use top and left to center the <li> element within the <ul>

Comment: @Sim1-81 What are the values to dynamically center using top and left?

Comment: @Sim1-81 Also they seem to get smooshed into a ball lol.

Comment: sorry i totally miss the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `flexbox`
here is the updated fiddle:

also if you want to align from left please remove inline `margin-left` set to `li`

```css
.nav_bar_container {
  background: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

.nav_child{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_bar_container align-center">
  <ul id="nav_bar">
    <li  class="nav_child">
      <svg height="100" width="100">
            <circle id="About" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke-width="3" class="expand active"> </circle>
            <text>
                <b> About </b>
            </text>
        </svg>
    </li>
    <li  class="nav_child">
      <svg height="100" width="100">
            <circle id="Experience" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke-width="3" class="expand disabled"> </circle>
        </svg>
      <span>
            <b> Experience </b>
        </span>
    </li>

  </ul>
  <div>
```

Comment: It does not seem to be working for me. I have a container that stretches the full height, but the nav_bar <ul> doesn't seem to be vertically centered which I am guessing is preventing its children from vertically centering also.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be working now!

I don't think you need the css for the nav_child, I was also to remove that and it still worked well.